# Windows 上の Sublime Text 3 に Tern をインストールするには？

Tags: windows, sublimetext

MACの情報しか見つからないのですが、windows10だと下記のパスに tern_for_sublime-master フ‌​ォルダを入れてインストールをnpmで行う‌​のでしょうか？

参考サイト https://liginc.co.jp/312755

参考サイトを見ると
まず初めに `C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\package` に
tern_for_sublime-master フォルダをそのまま入れてやればよいのでしょうか？

次にgulpを使っているのでnode自体は入っているので、 windows10だと `C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\package\tern_for_sublime-master` をカレントディレクトリとしてどんなコマンドを打てばよいのでしょうか？

`npm install tern` ではないですよね？

コメントの通りにやってみましたが下記のようにエラーが出ました。

```
AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\tern_for_sublime-master>npm install
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\h\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\tern_for_sublime-master\package.json'
npm WARN tern_for_sublime-master No description
npm WARN tern_for_sublime-master No repository field.
npm WARN tern_for_sublime-master No README data
npm WARN tern_for_sublime-master No license field.
```

なぜか入れ子になっていたのでフォルダを入れ子にならないようにしたところ一瞬インストールと出るようになりました。

その結果
Preferences > Package Settings > Tern > Settings – User
に

```
{
    "tern_argument_hints": true,
    "tern_output_style": "status",
    "tern_argument_completion": true,
    "auto_complete": true,
    "auto_complete_triggers": [
        {"selector": "text.html", "characters": "<"},
        {"selector": "source.js", "characters": "."}
    ]
}
```

を追加するところまでおかげさまでできました。
ただ
document.getElementsByClassName
と打ってコントロール、スペースを押しても（）と出てきません。
こちらを行う前とあまり変化を感じません。
引数か代入かわかるように保管してくれないのでしょうか？

dcmt.addEvtLisrが
dcmt.addEventListener
と変化はします。これは使えていると考えてよいのでしょうか？

console.log(i);
を記載すると下記のリンクやlog()などの英語の解説がサブライムテキスト３上に出るようになりました。
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/log

恐らくインストール自体はできたように見えます。

ただdocument.getElementsByClassNameと入力してコントロールとスペースを押しても、
引数か代入かのヒントが出てきません。

Comment: tern for sublimeが正常に展開されていないようです。フォルダ内にpackage.jsonなどのファイルが来るように配置してから再試行してみてください。

Answer (score 1):

> まず初めに `C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\package` に
>   tern_for_sublime-master フォルダをそのまま入れてやればよいのでしょうか？

gitを導入されていない場合はその通りです。

> 次にgulpを使っているのでnode自体は入っているので、 windows10だと
>   `C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\package\tern_for_sublime-master` をカレントディレクトリとしてどんなコマンドを打てばよいのでしょうか？

`npm install`でNodeモジュールをインストールしてください。この時にTernがnode_modulesフォルダにインストールされます。

---

追記について：
`console.log()`で補完と解説が出ているということなので、インストールはできています。
デフォルトでは汎用性を優先してECMAScriptで定義されたものやNode.jsで標準的なものだけが補完されるようです。
`document`や`Document.addEventListener(..)`等のウェブブラウザ向けの補完を使う場合は、プロジェクトフォルダ、もしくはデフォルトのTern設定に次のような設定ファイルが必要になります。

.tern-project :

```
{
  "libs": [
    "browser",  // ウェブブラウザ用の補完設定
    "jquery"    // jQuery用の補完設定
  ]
}
```

デフォルトのプロジェクトフォルダはTern for Sublimeをインストールしたフォルダ内のdefault_project_dir というフォルダになります。
そこに上記のJSONを書いた .tern-project を設置して、Sublime Textを再起動してみてください。

Comment: gulpを使っているのでnodejsはインストールされていますがnodejsをインストールするのですか

Comment: `npm install`はTern for Sublimeに必要なnode.jsのモジュール（Ternを含む）を一括インストールするコマンドです。そもそもnode.jsが無ければnpmコマンドは使えないはず…

Comment: なぜか入れ子になっていたのでフォルダを入れ子にならないように

Comment: 追加情報を見てもらえましたか？

Comment: 返答遅くなりましたが、回答を追記しました。`document.addEventListener()`などはTern側の話で、ブラウザ用のオブジェクトや関数であるため、標準で補完されなかったようです。[前の質問](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/33649)に話が戻っている為、この追記は脱線気味ですね…。

Comment: 間違えていただいた回答に情報を追加してしまい恐縮です